# Rasa integration with Kafka

Tags: rasa, rasa-core, rasa-x

Configuring a kafka event broker as given in the rasa documentation [here](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/event-brokers/) gives an error at this specific line `tracker_store = InMemoryTrackerStore(domain=domain, event_broker=kafka_broker)` saying domain not found. I am assuming domain  here is the domain.yml file and it is in the working directory.

Did anyone successfully integrate rasa and kafka? Do I have to run broker and consumer as separate scripts to send and receive messages?

Edit: Rasa team updated their documentation a little later.

Comment: are you trying to implement this in python, or is reading it from the endpoint configuration an option ?

Comment: I tried both. With endpoints, I had an issue with inmemory tracker and with creating a broker script, I had an error which reads no brokers available.

Comment: could you post the error you get when using the endpoints file? You should only need to specify the event_broker in there, nothing about the tracker_store specifically

Comment: Hi @tejas, did you succeed ?

Comment: @William yes I could do it.